# Possible to generate Java class structure for SOAP request/response content

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm currently building a web service client for an application that soon will be introduced in my company. I've never worked with SOAP before but I figured out that I could generate a WS consumer with JAX-WS using the wsdl file. Now I want to marshal/unmarshal my requests/responses content with JAXB. The content will be everything inside the SOAP:envelope. So I was wondering if there is a way where I can generate Java objects for all the requests/responses I want to use. There are a lot of similarities between the diferent requests/responses but also some differences. Is it possible to create a structure of classes where similarities get reused? Declaring it all by hand seemed like a lot of work. But if there's no way to generate it, I'm affraid I'll have to. Can anybody help me? Or is there another way I can work better with the WS client? Thanks in advance.